# Leap 15.4 boot hangs on: fbo: switching to i915 from EFI VGA

Tags: linux, boot, opensuse, intel-graphics

HW: Asus mainboard Prime Z790-P iCore5 with integrated GPU, no additional graphic card OS: OpenSuse Leap 15.4 new installation and updated.

Installing the OS without the linux parameter nomodeset in grub was NOT possible. After installation boot without nomodeset is neither possible. But nomodeset inhibits the loading of the graphic drivers, hence the display is limited to 1024x768. 4:3 on a 16:9 Display which is very ugly.

On deleting the grub parameter splash=silent, I could see, that the boot hangs after:

reached target Initrd Root Device

Not very helpfull. Later I deleted also the linux grub parameter quiet, which showed me:

fbo: switching to i915 from EFI VGA
The kernel having a problem loading the x module, no more log information available. When booting with parameter nomodeset, journalctl shows a warning that graphic drivers are not available but nothing helpful.

on this line boot hangs for ever! Hwo has an idea how to overcome this bug? Thanks to everybody.

Comment: Assuming along with the recent mb you have a recent cpu, I would look to the bleeding edge kernel rather than stock 15.4. Suse will have it somewhere on their site. You may even have to install tumbleweed rather than 15.4 to get support for these latest devices.

Comment: 13th gen Intel requires at least 5.18 kernel but preferably use 6.0+ for optimal performance.

Comment: it's 12th generation iCore5. Neverthless, the hint with tumbleweed is correct. I did an "upgrade" of my leap 15.4 installation with tumbleweed and it works, easy without any problem!

Answer (score 0):

On "upgrading" the leap 15.4 installation with tumbleweed the bug is gone, and it works. This was true even for the openSUSE-Tumbleweed-GNOME-Live-x86_64-Current.iso with which I tested first from an USB stick.